# Does the term "Wallet credit" or "Store credit" makes more sense to users

Tags: e-commerce, copywriting

Working on the returns module of an ecommerce website and app, when the user returns something they can decide to get credit added to their virtual wallet (which can be used to buy other products on the same website).

We can't decide which of the terms is "Wallet credit" or "Store credit".

which do you think makes more sense. Any insights on this? or is there a better name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: I think I misunderstood the question a bit. You're referring to credits and not the storage medium. In this case, **Store credit** makes more sense. To draw a parallel, you put "currency" in your physical wallet and not "wallet currency". Hence for an e-commerce setup, Store credit or credit would be the more appropriate term. Example - "You've received $20 as Store credits in your wallet" or "$20 have been credited in your wallet"

P.S - If possible, try to get hold of this [excellent report on E-commerce UX](http://www.nngroup.com/reports/ecommerce-user-experience/) by NN/g. The design guidelines backed by research and survey can help you with future tasks.

Comment: Funny. I've never heard of Wallet Credit... to me it sounds really silly and talking to me as if I were a kid.

Comment: @insidesin I think this can also be a cultural thing.  I've seen a good number of e-commerce companies using it in US and India.

Comment: Perhaps. Here in Australia we call it a wallet 99% of the time, but never 'Wallet credit' online. It just sounds beyond wrong.

Comment: @insidesin hmm.  Makes sense. I too was referring to Wallet.  Editing the answer.

Comment: wallet credit means nothing to me. Store credit I have heard about before and understand and is tangible.

Comment: That's true. The answer was edited after I correctly understood the context.

Comment: Bitcoin and Paypal are wallets because they're portable, not bound to a single store/product. Google, and are blurring the line a bit, but it could be argued that they are like malls; they sell apps, music, books and so on. At any rate they are big enough to FEEL like you can spend your money on just about anything.

Comment: Yes. You can see my edited answer. Initially, I misunderstood the question and thought that OP was asking for a storage medium.

Answer (score 3):

Store credit.

Wallets are things you use in several stores. So for example if I get money from amazon to put in my wallet, I can go and spend it on ebay.com.

But what you're describing is limited to just the website you're currently on, more like a coupon or gift certificate. In other words, not 'portable'.

Answer (score 0):

I agree there is no rule here, but in my opinion, Wallet credit is a far more vague and ambiguous concept than store credit. You should aim to have descriptive labels that match real life context. In this particular situation I would advice to go with store credit as its more descriptive and more aligned with e-commerce particularly if users could also return products in store. It would be beneficial  to ask your users which term better represents the concept for them.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with 'Account credit'. Here in the UK, 'store' is more something you do rather than somewhere you go - you go to the shop. Appreciate that cultural boundaries are blurring, but I think that particularly for international use, everyone has an 'account' with you, but not everyone will immediately get the 'store credit' reference. On a related note: 'wallet' is a very masculine term (again, at least here in the UK). I'm not immediately aware of a more gender neutral term that sits between 'wallet' and 'purse'.